# Use sched module to run at a given time

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a python script that needs to run between two given times. I'm required to use the build in `sched` module as this script needs to be able to run directly on any machine that has python 2.7 as to reduce configuration time.  (SO CRON IS NOT AN OPTION)

A few variables define the settings for the time to run, here `set_timer_start=0600` and `set_timer_end=0900` are written in `HHMM`. I'm able to stop the script at the right time.

I don't know exactly how `sched` works (the python doc page doesn't make to much sense to me), but as far as I understand It runs at a date/time (epoch) while I only want it to run at a given time (`HHMM`).

Can anyone give me an example (or link) on how to use the scheduler and perhaps calculate the next run date/time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I got your requirements right, what you need is probably a loop, that will re-enter a task in the queue every time it will be executed. Something along the lines of:

```
# This code assumes you have created a function called "func" 
# that returns the time at which the next execution should happen.
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
while True:
    if not s.queue():  # Return True if there are no events scheduled
        time_next_run = func()
        s.enterabs(time_next_run, 1, <task_to_schedule_here>, <args_for_the_task>)
    else:
        time.sleep(1800)  # Minimum interval between task executions
```

However, using the scheduler is - IMO - overkilling. Using datetime objects could suffice, for example a basic implementation would look like:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
while True:
    if dt.now().hour in range(start, stop):  #start, stop are integers (eg: 6, 9)
        # call to your scheduled task goes here
        time.sleep(60)  # Minimum interval between task executions
    else:
        time.sleep(10)  # The else clause is not necessary but would prevent the program to keep the CPU busy.
```

HTH!

Comment: you just made my day, I'll be using the second solution as that is the easiest, keeping the first one as a backup (in case my boss has other plans)

Comment: @s4uadmin - Happy it was useful for you. Keep in mind that mine is a **very basic** implementation that would fail for example if you input stuff like start=23, stop=01 and does not consider minutes. However it should be trivial to improve on it by substituting the `if x in range` with a function `func(x)` that will return `True` or `False` according to your needs. :)