# How can I set time in this Python code?

Tags: python, time

```
def initialize(context):
    g.security = '000001.XSHE'
    set_benchmark('000300.XSHG')

def handle_data(context,data):
    security = g.security
    order(security, 100)
```

I want operation this code at 10:00 o'clock, how can write the code?

Comment: You will need to use `cron` or similar scheduling tool on your OS.

Comment: You could use `schedule` as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16786600/1603480

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sched` module or simply loop through datetime, although as AChampion points out, on a *nix platform, it's easier to use cron.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401042/use-sched-module-to-run-at-a-given-time) does into more detail about sched and datetime.

Essentially:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
while True:
    if dt.now().hour == 10: # for 10 o'clock
    initialize(context)
    handle_data(context,data)
    time.sleep(60)  # Minimum interval between task executions
else:
    time.sleep(10)  # The else clause is not necessary but would prevent the program to keep the CPU busy.
```